# how to move an UIImageView image with swap like feature?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I want to build a simple application where there is a image presnt in uiimageview and when user swap the image to left ,right ,up or down with finger it will move to that corresponding direction .

Any solution??

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Apple's MoveMe sample